# Let members choose their own web parts in an Intranet site Sidebar

Tags: web-part, 2013, user-profile-service, personalization

I need to setup an Intranet site where site members can personalise & manage the web parts that appear for them in the sidebar (on the master page).

For example - one member may choose to have a 'my links' web part and a 'twitter' web part in their sidebar and another member may want to have a 'weather' web part and a 'my collegues' web part in their sidebar.

Is this possible? and if so how could it be done? Is integration with the user profile service required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to target audience the web parts and allow users to "subscribe" to the web parts they want?  I have not tried it but it may be possible with a list and a workflow - allow users to select the web parts they want to see and then have the workflow add them to the appropriate group so they are included in the target audience?

Comment: Thanks Dave, that seems like a good solution. Just may mean having lots of groups ha. Let me know if you think of any other solutions and if not I think I will roll with that :)